# creating linux super user shortcut

Tags: linux

In Lubuntu I am trying to create a Matlab desktop shortcut that opens Matlab as superuser.

In `/usr/share/applications` I created a file called `matlab.desktop` as follows:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=matlab
Comment=matlab su
Exec=sudo /usr/local/bin/matlab
Icon=/home/ebox/Desktoop/Matlab_Logo.png
Type=Application
Categories=Development
Terminal=false
```

When removing `sudo` in `Exec`, the shortcut works. However with `sudo` it does nothing. Is there a way to create this shortcut to open as SU?

**EDIT**
My modified `matlab.desktop` looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Matlab
Comment=matlab_root
Exec=gksudo -u root /usr/local/bin/matlab
Icon=/home/ebox/Desktop/Matlab_Logo.png
Categories=Development
Type=Application
```

Comment: `sudo` requires a terminal (to enter the password). Try `gksudo` instead, it will give you a dialog.

Comment: This briefly shows Matlab trying to open by it breaks down after about 1 sec. Matlab doesn't start, it only shows the image that Matlab is loading. I have added the edited `matlab.desktop` script in the Question.

Comment: Try just `gksu /usr/local/bin/matlab`.

Comment: I tried that, but it does the same: it attempts to open Matlab (showing the program loading image) but breaks down after about 1 sec.

Comment: Then Matlab probably has some trouble running as root. Try it from a terminal and see if you get anything in STDERR.

Comment: From a terminal it opens as root w/o any problem. I then `sudo su`  into root and open Matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use gksudo or gksu for this.

```
Exec=gksudo -k -u root /usr/local/bin/matlab
```

If it is not already there, you can install using the command

```
apt-get install gksu
```

For more reference check the link

https://askubuntu.com/questions/118822/how-to-launch-application-as-root-from-unity-launcher

Comment: The command `Exec=gksudo -k -u root /usr/local/bin/matlab`
doesn't open Matlab as SU on my computer but as a normal user. I have tried several things. I removed `-k` and it briefly shows Matlab trying to start up but this breaks down within a second. The same goes for when I remove `-k -u root` and leave it as `Exec=gksudo /usr/local/bin/matlab`.

I have edited my `matlab.desktop` file in the question.